# Column values to one row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to SQL and I have 4 columns similar to this and I would like to get the value into one row with some additional text.

| ID | Code_name | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Price | 100 | Apple |
| 1 | Vat | 25 | Apple |
| 1 | Service Fee | 5 | Apple |
| 2 | Price | 200 | Apricot |
| 2 | Vat | 50 | Apricot |
| 2 | Service Fee | 5 | Apricot |
| 3 | Price | 300 | Mango |
| 3 | Vat | 75 | Mango |
| 3 | Service Fee | 10 | Mango |

But I would like to get the values in this way:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | x100p/x25v/x5s |
| 2 | Apricot | x200p/x50v/x5s |
| 3 | Mango | x300p/x75v/x10s |

I have tried:

```
SELECT ID, 
NAME,
CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'PRICE' THEN RC.AMOUNT ELSE NULL END PRICE,
CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'VAT' THEN RC.AMOUNT ELSE NULL END VAT,
CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'SERVICE FEE' THEN RC.AMOUNT ELSE NULL END SERVICE FEE
FROM PRODUCTS
```

But it returns

| ID | Name | Price | Vat | Service Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 100 | null | null |
| 1 | Apple | null | 25 | null |
| 1 | Apple | null | null | 5 |
| 2 | Apricot | 200 | null | null |
| 2 | Apricot | null | 50 | null |
| 2 | Apricot | null | null | 5 |
| 2 | Mango | 300 | null | null |
| 2 | Mango | null | 75 | null |
| 2 | Mango | null | null | 10 |

Anyone have ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I am not in front of a computer, but you could try to PIVOT to achieve this in MS SQL Server

Comment: Please explain the logic for producing the values you want.  They are not in the original data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and concatenate the values:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
       ( MAX(CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'PRICE' THEN RC.AMOUNT END) || '/' ||
         MAX(CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'VAT' THEN RC.AMOUNT END) || '/' ||
         MAX(CASE WHEN CODE_NAME = 'SERVICE FEE' THEN RC.AMOUNT END) 
       ) as value
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY ID, NAME;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add the bits of text as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data, then concatenate the values from the resulting columns, adding the extra bits you need. Something like this. (Notice the `with` clause, which is not part of the solution; I only use it for testing. Remove it, and use your actual table and column names in the `select` statement.)

```
with
  products (id, code_name, value, name) as (
    select 1, 'Price'      , 100, 'Apple'   from dual union all
    select 1, 'Vat'        ,  25, 'Apple'   from dual union all
    select 1, 'Service Fee',   5, 'Apple'   from dual union all
    select 2, 'Price'      , 200, 'Apricot' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Vat'        ,  50, 'Apricot' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Service Fee',   5, 'Apricot' from dual union all
    select 3, 'Price'      , 300, 'Mango'   from dual union all
    select 3, 'Vat'        ,  75, 'Mango'   from dual union all
    select 3, 'Service Fee',  10, 'Mango'   from dual
  )
select id, name, 'x' || p || 'p/x' || v || 'v/x' || s || 's' as value
from   products
pivot  (max(value) for code_name in ('Price' p, 'Vat' v, 'Service Fee' s))
order  by id
;

 ID NAME    VALUE                   
--- ------- ------------------------
  1 Apple   x100p/x25v/x5s          
  2 Apricot x200p/x50v/x5s          
  3 Mango   x300p/x75v/x10s
```

Or, you can use `listagg` like so:

```
select id, name,
       listagg('x' || value || decode(code_name, 'Price', 'p', 'Vat', 'v', 's'), '/')
           within group (order by decode(code_name, 'Price', 1, 'Vat', 2, 3))
       as value
from   products
group  by id, name
order  by id
;
```